# I am implementing redux into my react native project, but im unsure how I should initialise my initialState

Tags: react-native, redux

My problem is that I am unsure what type of actions/reducers I will need in my application. So far, I have chat, posts and users, but later into development, I am going to be implementing events, organisations and other such things that will need to be in the store, but I am not sure what or how many.

Every tutorial I have found has had all of the data types in the initialState objects (for example, an app with posts and todos has had them both in the initialState as empty arrays).

My question is whether this is necessary, or whether I can actually add the additional items to the store, without having to go and add them to my initial state to accommodate the new data.

E. G. If my initialState looked like this:

```
Const initialState = {
      users: []  }
```

Could I then add a post to the initial state and have it recognise a posts array without going back to the initialState and passing in a `posts: []` object?